# Filter iteration with multiple conditions

Tags: python

I would like to filter specific iterations in Python which matches multiple conditions

```
from itertools import combinations
iteration = combinations(range(5),3)
print(list(iteration))

[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

How can I filter all iterations which contain the numbers 0 AND 3?
ie: I want to remove (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 4)

Comment: You can use list comprehension ```[v for v in values if not (0 in v and 3 in v)]```

Comment: or you can use the built-in `filter` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imperative solution:

```
filteredList = []
for value in iteration:
  if (0 not in value and 3 not in value):
    filteredList.append(value)
```

Filter solution:

```
filteredList = list(filter(lambda value: 0 not in value and 3 not in value, iteration))
```

List comprehension solution (Thanks @Sushanth):

```
filteredList = [v for v in iteration if not (0 in v and 3 in v)]
```